# Can't get boost/asio to run

Tags: c++, serial-port, boost-asio

I'm trying to communicate with a serial port using boost/asio.  This is my code.

The calling function header file contains this:

```
    QserialPort *SerialPort;
```

The calling function:

```
    std::string port = "com1";
    SerialPort = new QserialPort(port);
```

The class header file contains this code:

```
    /* 
    * File:   QserialPort.h
    *
    * Created on December 13, 2012, 9:01 PM
    */

    #ifndef QSERIALPORT_H
    #define QSERIALPORT_H

    #include "global_variables.h"
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <winbase.h>
    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>
    #include <boost/system/system_error.hpp>
    #include <boost/asio.hpp>
    #include <boost/asio/serial_port.hpp>
    #include <QString>

    #define rcvBufSize 512
    #define xmtBufSize 512

    class QserialPort {
    public:
        QserialPort(std::string comPort);
        virtual ~QserialPort();
    private:
        // variables
        int m_a;
        double m_b;
        const char* m_c;
        boost::asio::io_service m_io;
        boost::asio::serial_port m_serialPort;
        char m_rcvMsg[rcvBufSize];
        char m_xmtMsg[xmtBufSize];

        // functions

    };

    #endif   /* QSERIALPORT_H */
```

The class source code has this constructor:

```
    QserialPort::QserialPort(std::string comPort) :
    m_io(),
    m_serialPort(m_io, comPort)
    {
        QString msg;
        char buf[100];
        sprintf(buf, "Serial port is on %s", comPort);
        msg.append(buf);
        QMessageBox::information(NULL, "debug", msg);
    }
```

The program compiles OK, but when I try to run it I get this error in a pop up window:

```
This application has requested the Runtime to teminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

This is what is in the run output tab of netbeans:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 
'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector
<boost::system::system_error> >'
  what():  open: The system cannot find the file specified
Unable to open SCSI controller 0:[\] , error code: 0x5
Unable to open SCSI controller 1:[\] , error code: 0x5

RUN FAILED (exit value 3, total time: 15s)
```

These are the examples I am following:

- http://www.ce.unipr.it/people/medici/boost_asio_serial_port.html
- http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Simple-serial-port-demonstration-with-boost-asio-asynchronous-I-O-td2582657.html
- http://www.webalice.it/fede.tft/serial_port/serial_port.html

My system:

```
Windows Vista Home Premium Service Pack 2
Netbeans 7.2.1
QtSDK 1.2.1
Boost 1.52.0
```

What do I need to do to get this to run.

Comment: Are you sure that "com1" is present in your system?

Comment: You don't show your call to `open`, but it appears you are using the versions of `asio` functions that throw exceptions when they fail.  In this case, it is failing to open the specified device (com1).